# python TextIOWrapper problem when opening a file

Tags: python

Why I am getting this output when trying to read a simple text file?

```
MT = open("MT.fasta")
print(MT)    

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='MT.fasta' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Every other time it gave me the contents of the file, but now it returns attibutes. Already tried closing an reopnening Spyder, but keep getting the same result.

Also tried to close and reopen the file itself, but to no avail

```
MT.close()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `MT` is the actual file (a `TextIOWrapper` object), not its contents. You can get the contents from that object using its `read` method (i.e. `MT.read()`) or other alternatives depending on your application, e.g. [`readlines`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readlines.asp), which I use the most. You can find more methods in the official [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Also note:

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file
> objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its
> suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using
> `with` is also much shorter than writing equivalent `try-finally` blocks:

```
with open('workfile') as f:
    read_data = f.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(MT.read())
```

will print the contents of your file.

files in python have methods to read them, write to them ...

here is a nice guide :

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation

Comment: But why it worked alright with print(MT) before and now i need to add .read()?

Comment: Check the link in my answer @Manuel

Comment: MT is a file object, you should use the method read() to access to its content, it shouldn't work without read(). look at the guide in the link it will explain many things about using files.

and the link I included should clarify everything about files, all the methods you need to read, write and pretty much do anything with files in a simple nice way, I hope I helped :)

Comment: It is weird I have been using the print(MT) no problem for a while now and it just stopped working today. However, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

MT is an object, and you should use it method `read()` to show the text.

```py
MT = open("MT.fasta", "r")
print(MT.read())
```

Comment: How is this any different from my answer? You have shamelessly copied my entire answer.

Answer (score 0):

To **read a file using python**, use the following syntax:

```
MT = open("MT.fasta", "r")
print(MT.read())
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp)